# How can I create an itemize list with date custom bullet

Tags: lists, itemize

I would like to have this render with an itemize environement :

[image: itemise]

Anyone to tell me clues about how to get it ?

I don't care about color and i can draw the arrows with tikz.

Best.

Comment: Have you seen the `enumitem` package? It has a `label` key which seems suits your needs.

Comment: IMHO, it's difficult to read. The baseline of the year should be the same as the baseline of the `itemize` list, belonging to the year. Then the whole list would have a consistent reading order from left to right and top to down. If the year is too low, the latter is destroyed and the eyes have to flicker, when moving to next year's (down) first entry (up).

Comment: Since itemize is mostly about hanging indentation, you might do the whole thing in tikz.